# AWS throttling for Code Commit

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am getting below error when I'm doing git operations on a Code Commit repository. The number of operations is in the range of tens in few minutes - adding/removing/pulling files.

Is this because of AWS throttling or something else?
If so, what's the limit and how do I increase it in AWS?

`"interim_desc": "RequestId: 12e27770db854bf0a6034cd6f851717d. 'git fetch origin --depth 20' returned with exit code 128. 
error: RPC failed; HTTP 429 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 429 Too Many Requests: The remote end hung up unexpectedly'"`

Comment: HTTP 429 is used to indicate rate limiting, and I would expect AWS to use the HTTP status codes correctly. Are you also using the same account to access other services? If so, perhaps they are causing the request limit to be reached.

Comment: I am also using API gateway, but this should not cause problems I think - tens of requests as compared with default throttling limit of 10k. I suspect this is related to code commit limits, but I could not find any rate limits in the aws docs.

Comment: @MiN- I am also facing the similiar issue. Can you please let me know how to increase in rate limit? if possible please share the link if you feel Amazon will charge more for this?

Comment: Also facing a similar problem. Unfortunately the docs don't have enough info

Answer (score 2):

Here is the manual how to handle 429 error while accessing CodeCommit:

Access error: “Rate Exceeded” or “429” message when connecting to a CodeCommit repository
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ae.html#troubleshooting-ae3

I would copy here the most noteable part:

**Implement jitter in requests, particularly in periodic polling requests**.
If you have an application that is polling CodeCommit periodically and this application is running on multiple Amazon EC2 instances, introduce jitter (a random amount of delay) so that different Amazon EC2 instances do not poll at the same second. We recommend a random number from 0 to 59 seconds to evenly distribute polling mechanisms across a one-minute timeframe.

......

**Request a CodeCommit service quota increase in the AWS Support Center**.
To receive a service limit increase, you must confirm that you have already followed the suggestions offered here, including implementation of error retries or exponential backoff methods. In your request, you must also provide the AWS Region, AWS account, and timeframe affected by the throttling issues.